# "figlie di" vs. "figli di"

Tags: word-choice

Ciao, sono qui a chiedere spiegazioni circa un problema cui pensai mentre scrivevo questo:

> Sì, esiste un legame preciso fra "a" e "b", sono *costruzioni* culturali figlie della medesima propaganda.

In realtà, per rendere l'idea che "a" e "b" fossero *costruzioni* culturali surrettizie, avrei voluto usare *artefatti* al posto *costruzioni*, poi ho notato che operando la sostituzione avrei dovuto usare 'figli' dopo - perché artefatti è maschile - e non 'figlie', ma desistetti perché 'figli della medesima propaganda' sembrava strano.

È una mia impressione? o c'è una ragione per cui dovremmo preferire 'figlie di' lì, piuttosto che 'figli di'?

Comment: Non mi è chiara la domanda: se usi metaforicamente “figlio [di un'epoca, di un evento etc.]” detto di qualcosa, se quel qualcosa è femminile userai “figlia”, certo. Che cosa stai chiedendo di preciso?

Comment: Quindi “*Sì, esiste un legame preciso fra "a" e "b", sono artefatti culturali figli della medesima propaganda.*” non suona strano?

Comment: No, non suona strano: “artefatto” è maschile, ”costruzione” è femminile.

Answer (score 2):

É corretto che il genere cambi, la parola è il soggetto della frase subordinata.

`Artefatto` è di genere maschile, quindi è corretto `figlio/figli`.

`Costruzione` è di genere femminile, quindi è corretto `figlia/figlie`.

Forse un diverso uso della punteggiatura renderebbe la frase più chiara (riporto entrambe):

> Sì, esiste un legame preciso fra "a" e "b": sono costruzioni culturali, [le quali sono] figlie della medesima propaganda.
>
> Sì, esiste un legame preciso fra "a" e "b": sono artefatti culturali, [i quali sono] figli della medesima propaganda.

Un'altra possibilità è mantenere il genere di "a" e "b" a prescindere (questo potrebbe far suonare "strana" la frase in caso di discordanza).